# Can iOS Subscription IAP be used across multiple apps?

Tags: ios, mobile, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have an existing paid app (App A) that is essentially an island of data on the device it is installed on. I am working on a similar app (App B) that will be backed by an azure mobile service and provide data sync etc. App B will be a subscription based app due to the ongoing server side costs.

I want to eventually bring App A into the fold of the subscription model but was wondering is it possible for App A to use the same subscription as App B? So if a user has subscribed to App A and then logs into App B they are a valid subscribed user and vice versa.

Also, if it helps, my users will have a local account in my system username/password/email/uid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve the desired functionality with the help of your server.

You can keep track of whether user is a subscribed user or not on your server.

So when he logs in to app A, you can check with your server about his subscription status. If he has subscribed using app B then you can continue him as a subscribed user on app A also or vice versa. In case, he is not a subscribed user, then show him the option of subscribing.

Comment: So does this mean that both app A and B have separate IAP items setup for subscriptions? I'm assuming there is no way to share an actual IAP item across multiple apps. Then on my server side I dont really care that they may be different IAP items they are treated as the same based on product id? What do I use to correlate the subscriptions on my end so I know that "Monthly Subscription" is treated as the same from both apps on my end?

Comment: yeah the product id is the key here. You know what is the product id for monthly subscription for app A and B. So setup the logic accordingly on your server side to treat them similarly and provide the user with subscription of both the apps.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think Apple does not agree that so you add IAP's for with each app different from. If you sold more more IAPS from different apps **apple will warn you.**

Thanks